# Make a column based on conditions and previous columnb in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-management

I have a dataset like this :

```
structure(list(Q3.3 = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male"), Q6.2 = c("Yes", "NE", "Yes", "NE", "Yes", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "No", "NE", 
"Yes", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", 
"No", "NE", "Yes", "NE"), Q6.3 = c("3", "NE", "2", "NE", "1", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"3", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "2", "NE"), Q6.4 = c("Yes", "NE", "No", "NE", "No", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "No", "NE", "No", 
"NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", 
"No", "NE"), Q6.5 = c("3", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE"), Q7.5_1 = c("Yes", "", "Yes", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "No, this was available, but I did not use it", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Yes", ""), dataname1 = c("Q", 
"Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", 
"Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", 
"Q", "Q", "Q"), Q7.5_1_bb = c("Yes", "NE", "Yes", "NE", "Yes", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "No", "NE", 
"No, this was available, but I did not use it", "NE", "NE", "No", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "Yes", "NE")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I want to mirror "NE" values to Q7.5_1 and also need to code  "Q7.5_1" column again "NE"

If **NOT** Q6.3 = 2 Or Q6.3 = 3 Or Q6.3 = 4 Or Q6.3 = 5 Or Q6.3 = 6 Or Q6.3 = 7 Or Q6.3 = 8 Or Q6.3 = 9 Or Q6.3 = 10

**Or If** Q6.5 = 2 Or Q6.5 = 3 Or Q6.5 = 4 Or Q6.5 = 5 Or Q6.5 = 6 Or Q6.5 = 7 Or Q6.5 = 8 Or Q6.5 = 9 Or Q6.5 = 10

**Or If** Q6.3 = 1 And Q6.5 = 1

```
df<-df %>% mutate(Q7.5_1_bb = if_else(
  !(Q6.3 %in% c(2:10)) | Q6.5 %in% c(2:10) | Q6.3 == 1 & Q6.5 == 1,
  Q6.2, Q7.5_1))
```

When I used the above code, some of the values were weritten, like the row 5

```
    Q3.3 Q6.2 Q6.3 Q6.4 Q6.5 Q7.5_1  Q7.5_1_bb

1   Female  Yes 3   Yes 3   Yes     Yes
2   Male    NE  NE  NE  NE          NE
3   Female  Yes 2   No  NE  Yes     Yes
4   Male    NE  NE  NE  NE          NE
5   Female  Yes 1   No  NE          Yes
```

While I expect to  see NE in Q7.5_1_bb in row 5.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the below answer  is what I expext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be this:

```
newdf <- structure(list(Q3.3 = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
                        "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
                        "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
                        "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                        "Female", "Male"), Q6.2 = c("Yes", "NE", "Yes", "NE", "Yes", 
                                                    "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "No", "NE", 
                                                    "Yes", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", "NE", "No", "NE", "NE", 
                                                    "No", "NE", "Yes", "NE"), Q6.3 = c("3", NA, "2", NA, "1", NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "3", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", NA), Q6.4 = c("Yes", "", "No", 
                                                                                                                                      "", "No", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "No", "No", "", "No", 
                                                                                                                                      "", "", "No", "", "", "", "No", "", "", "No", "", "No", ""), 
               Q6.5 = c("3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                        NA, NA, NA), Q7.5_1 = c("Yes", "", "Yes", "", "", "", "", 
                                                "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "No, this was available, but I did not use it", 
                                                "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Yes", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
     
# Conditional
newdf2 <- newdf %>% mutate(Q7.5_1_bb = case_when(
  !(Q6.3 %in% c(2:10)) ~ if_else(Q6.3 == 1, 
                            if_else(Q6.5 == 1, Q7.5_1, "NE"), Q7.5_1),
    Q6.5 %in% c(2:10) ~ Q7.5_1,
  TRUE ~ "NE"
  )
  )
```

Comment: Great code, could you help me how can I change the code to have just spesific values from the corresponding column and also those who are not eligble for the condition will be "NE"

Comment: What do you mean by having just specific values from the corresponding column? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Based on the conditions that I mentioned above, row 5 is not eligible for Q7.5_1, and it should be coded "NE". Whit this code the "yes" from Q6.2  was appeared in Q7.5_1_bb, while I want to have NE.

Comment: I may have understood wrong, but the first condition was that Q6.3 should not be among values 2 to 10. This condition is met for the column 5 (`Q6.3 == 1`). Also, I have edited for it to add "NE" when none of the conditions is met.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This condition will be met when both (Q6.3 == 1 & Q6.5 == 1) were there, while we have one of them.

Comment: In a better definition, once the conditions have been met we should keep the value from Q7.5_1, otherwise they won't be eligble. Do you think case_when can work for it?

Comment: So, what you mean by "If not Q6.2 is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 **OR IF** Q6.2 == 1 and Q6.5 == 1", you mean "**AND IF**", correct?

Comment: The way you made the conditions is exactly right. The issue is in my data, and you may able to help. When we refere to Q6.2,  the "yes" is on both Q6.2 and Q7.5_1. So,  with your code, we have changed the actual frequeny of Q7.5_1. The survey  already did not ask who were  not eligble, and I can code those blank cells "NE" . But I want to detect missings too. If you run the updted code I have provided and chack the frequency you will see the distribition has changed and it is not your problem. I think for males we can correspond Q6.2, but for females who are "NE" we need another column.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you check it out to see if it works now?

Comment: Thak you do much. It is what I need.